# Crash when trying to save to NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, nsuserdefaults

When I try to save the current level count to NSUserDefaults in the `applicationWillTerminate` function it crashes on me. Why ?

-----------------------  AppDelegate.m -----------------------

```
        - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
            CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];

            HelloWorldLayer *hWClass = [[HelloWorldLayer alloc]init];

            NSNumber *lCount = [NSNumber numberWithInt:hWClass -> level];

            hWClass -> lvlCount =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [hWClass -> lvlCount setObject:lCount  forKey:@"levelCount"];



            [[director openGLView] removeFromSuperview];

            [viewController release];

            [window release];

            [director end]; 
        }
```

-----------------------  HelloWorldLayer.h -----------------------

```
        ...{
        @public
        int level;
        NSUserDefaults *lvlCount;
        int health;
        ...
        }
        @property (nonatomic,retain) NSUserDefaults *lvlCount;
```

-----------------------  HelloWorldLayer.m -----------------------

```
  NSNumber *currentLevel = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"levelCount"];
        if (currentLevel != nil){
        int cLevel = [currentLevel integerValue];

        [self generateLevelFromPlist:cLevel];
        }else{
            [self generateLevelFromPlist:1];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the instance variable directly by using `->` and then assigning it an autoreleased value. You need to access the property using dot syntax for it to properly be retained.

```
   hWClass.lvlCount =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   [hWClass.lvlCount setObject:lCount  forKey:@"levelCount"];
```

Also change the following variable declarations to private by remove `@public` or changing it to `@private` so you do not have that issue anymore.

```
    ...{
    @private
    int level;
    NSUserDefaults *lvlCount;
    int health;
    ...
    }
```